# SQL Server Inner Join Where clause

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

My problem is I can not query the matching records.

Queries should do the following:

```
ID | Name   | Value
-- | ------ | ------
1  | Color  | Red
1  | Color  | Blue
1  | Color  | Green
1  | Sizes  | 1cm
1  | Sizes  | 5cm
2  | Color  | Yellow
2  | Color  | Green
2  | Sizes  | 5cm
2  | Sizes  | 10cm
```

**Query 1:**

- Color = Red OR Blue
  -AND-
- Sizes = 1cm

Return matching records (ID=1)

**Query 2:**

- Color = Yellow OR Green
  -AND-
- Sizes = 5cm

Return matching records (ID=1,2)

My query :

```
SELECT a.ID, b.Name, c.Value
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.Id = b.aId
INNER JOIN table3 c ON b.ID = c.bId
WHERE (c.Value = (CASE b.Name WHEN 'Color' THEN 'Red' END)
       OR
       c.Value = (CASE b.Name WHEN 'Color' THEN 'Blue' END)
      )
  AND (c.Value = (CASE b.Name WHEN 'Sizes' THEN '1cm' END))
```

It does not work that way :(

I will be glad if you can help me.

Comment: THis is definitely not the way to setup database tables. Look into Normalization, google or Wikipedia even.

Comment: @Edward is correct.  SQL is a powerful language *if* the tables it operates on are normalized.  If not, you'll spend a lot of wasted time trying to shove a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: @SezMe EAV is not not normalized. Although it is problematic for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Just to return all the rows, you need something like this:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.Name, c.Value
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.Id = b.aId
INNER JOIN table3 c ON b.ID = c.bId
WHERE ((b.Name = 'Color' and c.Value in ('Red', 'Blue'))
       OR
       (b.Name = 'Sizes' and c.Value = '1cm')
      )
```

But you might actually want to do this, check where both criteria matches:

```
SELECT a.ID, b2.Name, c2.Value
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b2 ON a.Id = b2.aId
INNER JOIN table3 c2 ON b.ID = c2.bId
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table2 b  
              JOIN table3 c ON b.ID = c.bId
              WHERE a.Id = b.aId 
                AND b.Name = 'Color' 
                AND c.Value in ('Red', 'Blue')) 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table2 b  
              JOIN table3 c ON b.ID = c.bId
              WHERE a.Id = b.aId 
                AND b.Name = 'Sizes' 
                AND c.Value = '1cm')
```

Comment: How can I get the fields in your 2nd query (Name and Value)

Comment: You can join the tables the same way in that query too. Having different alias might make it more clear